# XMPP Authentication failed if I use X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism

Tags: iphone, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I am trying to make a facebook chat application.
And I want to login to XMPP server via X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism.
But I failed when I got the authentication step.
If I use DIGEST-MD5 mechanism, I can login to XMPP server successfully.(In this case, I used JID as username@chat.facebook.com and Password as my facebook password)
For X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism, I used JID as uid@chat.facebook.com and there were no problem with fetching my access token, uid, expiration date, etc..
Ofcoursely, I got 'xmpp_login' permission from facebook.

What was wrong?

Here is the decoded log message.

```
AppDelegate: xmppStream:socketDidConnect:
SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='chat.facebook.com'>
RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="FAA1CDE5" from="chat.facebook.com" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
SEND: <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM'/>
XMPPCapabilities: My capabilities:
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
  <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
  <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"/>
</query>
RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
      version=1&method=auth.xmpp_login&nonce=0E51AA2E42C4AF8FCE9D996F347C7019</challenge>
SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
    method=auth.xmpp_login&nonce=0E51AA2E42C4AF8FCE9D996F347C7019&access_token=BAAEctIrR99oBAM9ZBymJSDmVZAYb82RX634ANVZCQ9VJeoD9ZCTqSGVyuxSQfbm9s92VGtwcewVJlP7C8CnIglkqZBCvq6ZBxxWhJoDmK0rPJGdM5i7KRu18bZAJoyKEI0ZD
    &api_key=313036725417946
    &call_id=150701328
    &v=1.0</response>
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
AppDelegate: xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:
AppDelegate: xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the similar problem and solved the issue by securing the xmppstream before authentication

```
-(void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender{

DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

isXmppConnected = YES;

if (![xmppStream isSecure])
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL result = [xmppStream secureConnection:&error];

    if (result == NO)
    {
        DDLogError(@"%@: Error in xmpp STARTTLS: %@", THIS_FILE, error);
        NSLog(@"XMPP STARTTLS failed");
    }
}
else
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL result = [xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData] error:&error];

    if (result == NO)
    {
        DDLogError(@"%@: Error in xmpp auth: %@", THIS_FILE, error);
        NSLog(@"XMPP authentication failed");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try " -uid@chat.facebook.com " instead of " uid@chat.facebook.com ".